# How to use ffmpeg command to record the rtsp stream to wav

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, wav

I know how to record the rtsp steam to aac, just like:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.192/110 -acodec copy -t 5 -vn voice.aac`

But I don't know how to record the rtsp stream to wav. I have tried the below commands, but they can't work

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.192/110 -acodec copy -t 5 -vn voice.wav
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.192/110 -acodec copy -t 5 -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -f wav voice.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.192/110 voice.wav
```

`-acodec copy`/`-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (like a copy and paste). So if your input format is not compatible with the output format you'll get an error or an invalid output.